# How to change Mac OS X iCal's calendar color for Microsoft Exchange server account?

Tags: ical, exchange-activesync, color, macos

I'm using iCal for managing my schedules in my company. And my company is using Microsoft Exchange server for schedules. When I added the company account to iCal, it set the calendar color as *orange*. I have been using *blue* for my working schedule. So it's confusing me so much!

Usually, other accounts support changing the color by clicking *Get Info* menu. But this Exchange account doesn't show any configurable options. How can I change the color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this issue is specific to Lion. You can't even get to the info screen for an Exchange calendar, to make the colour choice shown in the screen shots here. Googling,  I turned up the following Applescript to accomplish the task:

```
tell application "iCal"
  set color of calendar "Calendar" to choose color default color {0, 0, 0}
end tell
```

Comment: This works like a charm!

Comment: The script works, but how do we change color of delegated calendars of the same name? http://cl.ly/1i45182J2y3i0I3J0T1X

Answer (score 5):

I'm running Snow Leopard and my iCal Get Info command allows me to change colors.  Here's a screen capture where I can make this change.

[image]

To reach this window, I highlight the exchange "Calendar" in the left hand sidebar of iCal and enter Cmd I.

In my iCal setup, I have "Home" (orange) "Gmail" (blue)and "Exchange" (red).  I can get info and change the color for any of the three calendars.  In my list, I have "Home", "Gmail" and "Exchange". Here is how 2 appts look:

[image]

What do you see when you get info on your exchange account?

Comment: This shows the color panel for calendars on other accounts, but not for Exchange account.

Comment: This is for my exchange account.  In my setup I have Gmail and exchange.  In either one, I can get info and change the color.

Comment: I pasted in an example in my answer above.

Comment: Doesn't do it! I tried right clicking and selecting Get Info... and every other calendar gives me the dialogue box you're talking about. Exchange calendars give nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After the recent Lion update, the color issue is resolved by right clicking on the desired exchange calendar, and selecting Get Info. A color combo box is now available. Prior to the update, only iCloud or local Calendars would allow color change in Lion.

Comment: Still an issue with delegate Exchange calendars on Sierra (OS X 10.12.6) and Calendar 9.0.