# How to change the color of Exchange's shared calendar in iCal in 10.10?

Tags: macos, calendar, ical, exchange

I've been in trouble for some days with the Exchange services on our Apple ecosystem. Right now, I want to change the color of the **shared** exchange calendars. Changing the color of the local calendar works, same for iCloud ones, and same for my own calendar. See screenshot below. System is in french as you can see…

[image: changing color of my own calendar]

**BUT** it doesnt work the same for the shared calendar. Here is when I right clic the calendar :

[image: right clic]

FYI when I right clic the name of the person above the calendar (on the screenshot it's behind the red rectangle) it just says something like (sorry for the translation) : open the delegate in a new window.

And then, once I clicked "read the informations", this is what I get. A great greyed selector :

[image: color selector greyed]

Of course when I click the color selector nothing happens. And when I click the "informations on the account" I get the account window, the one you get when you click in the menu on calendar > accounts.

Well, does anyone have an idea to change these damn colors ? I googled the thing but didn't find any consistent thing.

PS: there is a quite similar topic [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33753/how-to-change-mac-os-x-icals-calendar-color-for-microsoft-exchange-server-accou) on StackExchange but it doesn work for me since every shared calendar have the same name (and as you saw the calendar name is greyed too so it can't be changed).

THANKS !!

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem with our Office 365 Shared Calendars, but because these aren't user accounts there was no way for the owner to change the colour as there is no owner on these kinds of calendar. I eventually figured out a way of changing the colours which I've created a tutorial for here on my blog: http://matt-stone.co.uk/change-colours-microsoft-office-365-shared-calendars-apple-calendar-os-x/

Comment: Hi Matt, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: There's an update on this link that says: "UPDATE (1st May 2017): Several users have reported this tutorial no longer works in MacOS Sierra, I haven’t yet been able to test this myself yet as Apple Calendar is no longer my primary calendar app (I now use Fantastical 2). I will test and confirm this asap." However, no updates have been posted.

Comment: Doesn't work on Catalina, the colour just keeps reverting back to original even without starting the calendar app

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions from Matt Stone http://matt-stone.co.uk/change-colours-microsoft-office-365-shared-calendars-apple-calendar-os-x/ and I can confirm it worked for Mojave 10.14.6. I will update if it reverts overwriting the plist change.

An important part is making sure there are no active CalendarAgent processes. I might add a step of `ps ux|grep [C]alendarAgent` to check for them- and if still active, quitting more applications and re-doing the killall.

In case that page goes away: a command-line version of the instructions:

1. `cd Library/Calendars`
2. `grep -ir "human-readable unique name of calendar"`
3. search results will have a common directory pattern at the start.
4. cd that directory
5. there will be a subdirectory ending in ".exchange"
6. cd that directory.
7. `less Info.plist` - look for `<key>Color</key>` and the next line has a hex color. That color should match the old color as appeared in ical.
8. `killall -u yourusername CalendarAgent`
9. wait 30 seconds
10. `ps ux |grep [C]alendarAgent`
11. if anything is returned, you're still running something that restarted calendaragent. quit more things. Go back to 8.
12. `rm ~/Library/Calendars/Calendar\ Cache-bak`
13. `vim Info.plist` and replace the color with your preferred color.
14. re-start the calendar app. et voila!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in a Office365 domain. The solution was to let the owner of the calendar change the color in her own iCal. Then this color will change in other users iCal also.